# Backup single folder from Azure VM

Tags: azure, backup

I've set up a Windows Server 2012 R2 Azure virtual machine with SQL Server Web Edition.
I've set up a recovery services vault used to fully backup the Virtual Machine once a week, to be able to restore the installed software.
In SQL Server Management Studio, I've set up a Maintenance Plan that backs up the DB to a specific local folder in the virtual machine.

Now, I would like to back up this local folder to another location / storage in Azure, being able to restore this folder in case of need.

What's the best way to backup a single folder on a daily basis? 
Should I follow [this guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-configure-vault/) to "Back up a Windows Server or client to Azure using the Resource Manager deployment model"? Does the "Vault credential file and backup agent" works on a server in Azure too?
Are there any suggestions to perform the described plan?

Thank you very much!

Fabio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works without any issues on Azure Windows VM just the way it works on on-premises VM. If you want to backup a specific folder only, use the article you mentioned.